# Equations of a moving particle on a plane

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Equations of a moving particle on a plane:
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=x(t)\mathbf{i} + y(t)\mathbf{j}$$
$$\mathbf{v}(t)=\dot{\mathbf{r}}=\dot{x}(t)\mathbf{i} + \dot{y}(t)\mathbf{j}$$
$$\mathbf{a}(t)=\dot{\mathbf{v}}=\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=\ddot{x}(t)\mathbf{i} + \ddot{y}(t)\mathbf{j}$$
$$\mathbf{T}(t)=\frac{\mathbf{v}}{|{\mathbf{v}}|}=(cos(\phi(t)), sin(\phi(t)))$$
If $s(t)$ denotes the arc length along the curve then
$$\dot{s}=|\mathbf{v}|=\frac{ds}{dt}$$
$$\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{v}|\mathbf{T}=\dot{s}\mathbf{T}$$
$$\mathbf{a}=\dot{\mathbf{v}}=\frac{d}{dt}(\dot{s}\mathbf{T})=\ddot{s}\mathbf{T}+\dot{s}\frac{d\mathbf{T}}{dt}=\ddot{s}\mathbf{T}+\dot{s}^2\frac{d\mathbf{T}}{ds}$$

I don't get how in the last transformation we got $\dot{s}^2\frac{d\mathbf{T}}{ds}$ out of $\dot{s}\frac{d\mathbf{T}}{dt}$

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\dot{s}^2 \frac{dT}{ds} = \frac{ds}{dt} \frac{ds}{dt} \frac{dT}{ds} = \frac{ds}{dt} \frac{dT}{dt} = \dot{s} \frac{dT}{dt} $$

by the chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks!